# JsonRpcEngine: Response has no error or result for request

Tags: metamask, nft, mint, pinata, nextjs

I have an NFT marketplace project deployed on Vercel. I am having issue when minting the token. I upload them to Pinata without issue, the only thing when I call

```
const tx = contract?.mintToken(
        nftURI,
        ethers.utils.parseEther(price.toString()),
        {
          // Parse the etherString representation of ether into a BigNumber instance of the amount of wei
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.025).toString()),
        }
      );
      await toast.promise(tx!, {
        pending: "Minting Nft Token",
        success: "Nft has ben created!",
        error: "Minting error!",
      });
```

This has to work withot issue. I just tested the functionality and I am getting this error:

```
JsonRpcEngine: Response has no error or result for request:
{
  "method": "eth_estimateGas",
  "params": [
    {
      "value": "0x58d15e17628000",
      "from": "0x993db623bc2047dca85b5c359516595612a0dac4",
      "to": "0x427745c2bab32beb24f9b286ee5c0717b4d042f6",
      "data": "0xc046372c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005068747470733a2f2f676174657761792e70696e6174612e636c6f75642f697066732f516d503357755852636a513732527370797a4e6f446f59784d3448624a42454858474a647a54327931415764416800000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  ],
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 466633355,
  "origin": "https://next-js-nft-marketplace.vercel.app",
  "tabId": 604117792
}
```

What could be the wrong. It says "Response has no error or result for request", I think that means code is actually correct